# serverless - Type Error: Cannot read property 'Properties' of undefined

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

When issuing `serverless deploy --region eu-central-1`, I get the error

```
 Type Error ---------------------------------------------
 
  Cannot read property 'Properties' of undefined
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

This error only started after including

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
```

and can be reverted by commenting the plugin out. But I would like to use it for giving my lambda access to a DynamoDB.

The internet is pretty void about this error besides [this typo](https://forum.serverless.com/t/cant-get-rid-off-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-startswith-of-undefined/13273). The error is not [solved by a recent update (yet)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66821283/4575793) and the notice of serverless doesn't help much. `set SLS_DEBUG=*"` before deployment yields:

```
 Type Error ----------------------------------------------

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'Properties' of undefined
      at ServerlessIamPerFunctionPlugin.createRoleForFunction (C:\Users\XXXXX\MyProject\node_modules\serverless-iam-roles-per-function\dist\lib\index.js:273:25)
      at ServerlessIamPerFunctionPlugin.createRolesPerFunction (C:\Users\XXXXX\MyProject\node_modules\serverless-iam-roles-per-function\dist\lib\index.js:383:18)
      at PluginManager.invoke (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:579:20)
      at async PluginManager.spawn (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:601:5)
      at async Object.before:deploy:deploy [as hook] (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\deploy.js:60:11)
      at async PluginManager.invoke (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:579:9)
      at async PluginManager.run (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:639:7)
      at async Serverless.run (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:452:5)
      at async C:\snapshot\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:751:9

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Should I iunclude my `serverless.yml` in this post? It's quite large.

Answer (score 0):

Using some different key words I retrieved a [second (!) online search result](https://github.com/functionalone/serverless-iam-roles-per-function/issues/8#issuecomment-450483092), quoting:

> The plugin doesn't support working with the role property. You have the following in your provider sections: role: arn-for-deployment-role'. Try removing this.
>
> [More info here](https://github.com/functionalone/serverless-iam-roles-per-function#more-info)

This basically solves the issue and `serverless-iam-roles-per-function` worked after commenting out this:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  #iam: 
  #  role: CallsTableQueryRole
```

The reason for this could be, that previos versions (serverless < v2.24.0) used a different syntax than current ones. Compare:

```yaml
provider:
  #previously:
  iam: 
    role:
      statements:
  #≥ v2.24.0
  iamRoleStatements:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bref framework make sure to update bref in composer and serverless globally to the latest version